# Higher Order Functions using lambda for this question

Tags: python-3.x

I am learning a concept of higher order function. While I do understand most of it, I do not understand how this question is phrased/ what is it asking.

They give the higher order function Sum as follow:

```
def sum(term, a, next, b):
    if (a > b):
        return 0
    else:
        return term(a) + sum(term, next(a), next, b)
```

Write a function knocked_down(game) that takes in a game as a string and returns the number
pins knocked down in the game. Your function should use the higher-order function sum above, with the
following template:

```
    def knocked_down(game):
        # you may define t1, t2, t3, t4 here
        # and use it below
        return sum(t1, t2, t3, t4)
```

This question is regarding 10 pins bowling, here is 2 examples of the input and output:

```
knocked_down('XXX9/9/45421/XX')
95

or 

knocked_down('XXXXXXXXXX')
100
```

A X meaning strike, which means 10 pins are down. A number followed by a /, meaning it took 2 turns to take 10 pins down. 9/ means, 9 pins were down, and the remaining (1 pin left) was down on the 2nd try.

Im not sure what am I supposed to do to get t1, t2, t3, t3 using lambda as the term/next in Sum function

Answer (score 1):

The `sum()` function is [recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)). At each level, it uses a subordinate function `term()` to strip one bowling turn (either an 'X' character or two characters) from the string and convert it to number of pins down. Then it adds this turn result to the result of the remaining turns, calculated by a recursive call to `sum()`.

The function `sum()` doesn't get the game string. Instead, it works with indices `a` and `b`, where `a` is the current position in the game string, and `b` is the last position. Only the lambdas `term` and `next` recognize the game string, which means they should be [closures](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Closures).

Try to go on from this.

Comment: would you mind solving it? I am still not sure how to approach it

Comment: I'm not going to do your homework for you, but if you'll show some code you tried and what error or wrong result you got, then I can help you get unstuck.